# How to use multiple js files with Duktape?

Tags: javascript, embedded, duktape

I'm using Duktape in embedded MCU. For test case i have:
main.js file:

```
(function(){
    test();
})();
```

test.js file:

```
(function test(){
    print("func");
})
```

Both compiled as global default code and main.js is executed with duk_call(ctx, 0);

The problem is it throws error when calling a test() function.

I've also tried using just

```
function test() {
   print("test");
}
```

in test.js code, but it does not work either.

What I understand is that both files have separate execution context. That is why function is inaccessible.

But what is the right way to split code into multiple files for Duktape?

P.S. I am aiming to avoid using global context, because in documentation it is said that accessing variables is slow this way, that's why main.js looks that way.

P.P.S. I'm sure that test() function is unreachable, but I don't know how to write js code so that everything works.

P.P.P.S print() is a C function that outputs to serial port of esp32 and it works. even main.js works without a test() function call.

Comment: "it throws error when calling a test() function." Well great to hear, but what error does it give? What are you even thinking of accomplish by calling `print`? It is an embedded device and as such doesn't have a terminal unless you put that in.

Comment: i have print as c function and it works. i don't know what error it gives, i'm not very fluent at debugging duktape yet. but it is runtime error and it happens when function call is done, because if i put another print before function call, it outputs in terminal the string fine. i'm sure that function is unreachable and i'm asking about how to write js code right, so it is reachable.

Comment: The most important question is now, are you already embedding duck? If not tell so as that changes your question quite a bit.

Comment: it is embedded duktape running on esp32 and print function outputs to serial port and wirks fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you want is file import functionality. You can implement that in two ways:

1. Provide a function in your backend and export that to JS, to allow loading a file dynamically at runtime.
2. Implement module handling like in Node.js (which essentially also boils down to an import function).

The second idea is what is used most and implements a well defined approach to include other files in your JS application. Duktape comes with an extra file that implements the `require` command, just like in Node.js. You only have to provide your own functions for resolving a module and to load it from disk (as duktape has not file I/O support).

I implemented this approach in the [MGA tool in MySQL Workbench](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/tools/mga). The duktape file for implementing node module handling is [here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/8.0/tools/mga). The function to resolve modules (which includes handling of nested `node_modules` folders etc.) is implemented in the [ScriptingContext](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/tools/mga/src/library/scripting-context.cpp#L1521) class. The relevant part of it is this:

```cpp
/**
 * Part of the module loading machinery. JS interfacing is done by the duk_module_node code.
 * But we have to do the file work here. On the stack we get the value passed to `require()` as a "module ID" and
 * the ID of the calling script (which is empty for the main script).
 */
duk_ret_t ScriptingContext::resolveModule(duk_context *ctx) {
  // stack: [ requested_id parent_id ]
  std::string requestedID = duk_get_string(ctx, 0);
  std::string callingID = duk_get_string(ctx, 1);
  std::string parentPath = FS::isDir(callingID) ? callingID : Path::dirname(callingID);

  // Module resolution strategy in Node.js style: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together
  auto modules = getInternalModules();
  if (modules.find(requestedID) != modules.end()) {
    duk_push_string(ctx, requestedID.c_str());
    return 1;
  }

  ScriptingContext *context = ScriptingContext::fromDuktapeContext(ctx);
  std::string resolvedID;
  std::string cwd = Process::cwd();

  try {
    if (Path::isAbsolute(requestedID) || Utilities::hasPrefix(requestedID, ".")) {
      std::string temp;
      if (Path::isAbsolute(requestedID)) {
        temp = Path::relative(cwd, requestedID);
      } else
        temp = Path::join({ parentPath, requestedID });

      resolvedID = resolveFile(temp);
      if (resolvedID.empty())
        resolvedID = resolveFolder(context, temp);
    }
  } catch (std::runtime_error &e) {
    // Triggered for parse errors in package.json.
    context->throwScriptingError(ScriptingError::Syntax, e.what());
    return 0;
  }

  // No files found so far. Check node modules.
  if (resolvedID.empty()) {
    for (auto &folder : moduleFolders(parentPath)) {
      std::string path = Path::join({ folder, requestedID });
      std::string temp = resolveFile(path);
      if (!temp.empty()) {
        resolvedID = temp;
        break;
      }

      temp = resolveFolder(context, path);
      if (!temp.empty()) {
        resolvedID = temp;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if (resolvedID.empty()) {
    context->throwScriptingError(ScriptingError::Error, Utilities::format("Cannot resolve module %s", requestedID.c_str()));
    return 0;
  }

  duk_push_string(ctx, resolvedID.c_str());
  return 1;  // Use result on stack.
}
```

Comment: thank you for detailed explanation. i was thinking about modules, but was hoping it can be done more easily. thanks again!